# Discord.Net.Labs SlashCommands

Tags: c#, discord

Работаю в Discord.Net.Labs с slash командами. До этого работал с командами с префиксом. У команд с префиксом была удобная вещь, которая помогла их раснести по разным классам и при помощи [Command("name")], программа находила необходимый метод и выполняла его.

Попытался сделать тоже самое для slash команд, но не получилось.
Вот код для команд с префиксом:

```
var result = await commands.ExecuteAsync(context, PrefixPosition, services);
if (!result.IsSuccess)
   Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorReason);
if (result.Error.Equals(CommandError.UnmetPrecondition))
   await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ErrorReason);
```

А slash команды сделаны сейчас вот так:

```
switch (command.CommandName)
{
   case "role-info":
        await InfoMessage.SlashGetRoleInfo(command);
        break;
   case "server-info":
        await InfoMessage.SlashGetServerInfo(command);
        break;
```

Видел в документации, что есть `InteractionService.ExecuteCommandAsync(IInteractionContext, IServiceProvider)`, но не смог его реализовать.

Comment: Там ведь есть целая [документация](https://discordnet.dev/guides/int_framework/intro.html) на эту тему, как и примеры реализации. Так что `не смог его реализовать` - как бы, не отмазка) И да, смысл в .Labs если уже давно это все есть в оригинале?

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, я эту часть вообще не заметил, т.к пытался реализовать по аннологии с камандами с префиксом.

Comment: Не знаю, по какой вы там аналогии пытались реализовать, ибо вот вам [стандартные текстовые команды](https://discordnet.dev/guides/text_commands/intro.html), как видите, также регистрируется сервис, который следит за модулями, в слеш командах все +- тоже самое, только названия классов и методов другие. Просто надо было чуток получше изучить документацию, не останавливаясь на "базовом")